# Google Chome logs me out of linux account when I launch it

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

The title says it all. When I try to launch Google Chrome I am logged out completely from my Linux session.

I should mention that I have another user on my machine and this does not happen to them. It's just my user which suggests to me that there may be some sort of corrupted config or cache file for Chrome in my home directory. I just don't know which files I can/should try deleting.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have `google-chrome-stable` version 105.0.5195.102-1 installed.

Comment: Have you tried launching if from a terminal, redirecting all output to a file? It sounds like your chrome manages to crash your xserver  ... if the output doesn't provide much insight you could try adding `strace` to the mix, that might be a bit verbose, though. Also, have you checked `~/.xsession-errors`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`

Comment: You can always try to purge chrome completely and reinstall it to see if that is the case

Comment: The respective chrome-related files/directories are under `~/.config/` and `~/.cache/` - either named `chrome` or `google-chrome`. Deleting them altogether will be fine, except for losing your personal settings, cookies, bookmarks, etc.

Comment: @FelixJN Deleting the `google-chrome` directories in `~/.config/` and `~/.cache/` did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: @pormulsys I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome to no avail. Although by "purge chrome completely" you probably meant to include clearing chrome files in my home directory.